# UICollectionView custom layout in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, collectionview

i need realy help...

I need use custom layout in UICollectionView and I want get layout like image:

[image]

how to get this layout in swift?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to scroll the view? or is fixed?, 
Because if you are not scrolling you can use [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/index.html) and give the cell different Width multipliers.

But if you have to scroll you can use https://github.com/keighl/KTCenterFlowLayout and change the cell's size with the delegate methods from UICollectionView

Answer (score 0):

If the items are all the same size, you can use UICollectionViewFlowLayout and set its `itemSize`.

If the items are different sizes, you can use UICollectionViewFlowLayout 
and implement its `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` delegate method to return the desired sizes.

The bar across the top could be a `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader`, or simply a larger cell.

Answer (score 0):

For people who needs scrolling layout, could try **ScrollableStackView** library. Here is the github page :

https://github.com/gurhub/ScrollableStackView

Here is some sample codes :

**Swift**

```
import ScrollableStackView

var scrollable = ScrollableStackView(frame: view.frame)
view.addSubview(scrollable)

// add your views with 
let rectangle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 55))
rectangle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
scrollable.stackView.addArrangedSubview(rectangle)
// ...
```

**Objective-C**

```
@import ScrollableStackView

ScrollableStackView *scrollable = [[ScrollableStackView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
scrollable.stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillProportionally;
scrollable.stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
scrollable.stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
[self.view addSubview:scrollable];

UIView *rectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 55)];
[rectangle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

// add your views with
[scrollable.stackView addArrangedSubview:rectangle]; 
// ...
```

Hope it helps someone.